# grunt execution stops batch script

Tags: windows, batch-file, cordova, command-line, yeoman

I am doing development with cordova and yeoman + angularjs. I have adopted a folder structure as follows (output of dir command on windows):

```
C:\code\cordova\pg-droid-app>dir
 Volume in drive C is OSDisk
 Volume Serial Number is 404D-C81B

 Directory of C:\code\cordova\pg-droid-app

01/01/2015  03:46 PM    <DIR>          .
01/01/2015  03:46 PM    <DIR>          ..
01/01/2015  03:10 PM    <DIR>          pgdroid
01/01/2015  03:50 PM    <DIR>          pgdroid-app-frontend
01/01/2015  03:50 PM               241 showapp.bat
               1 File(s)            241 bytes
               4 Dir(s)  65,102,319,616 bytes free
```

`pgdroid-app-frontend` is the folder I've run `yo angular` (the yeoman generator-angular). `pgdroid` is the folder where the cordova project is setup.

Grunt is configured to copy output of my HTML dev work to `pgdroid\www` folder. It works fine.

Now to make things easier I've created the following batch script (`showapp.bat`):

```
echo === Running grunt... ===
cd pgdroid-app-frontend
grunt --force
echo === End Running grunt... ===
echo === Running cordova emulator ===
cd ..\pgdroid
cordova run android
cd ..
echo === End Running cordova emulator ===
```

The file is placed in the root directory (see the first output shared here). The script execution stops after grunt is executed. I am guessing this is the grunt program behaviour. It perhaps doesn't return a success exit code which may be the reason the script stops abrupt.

Whats the workaround for this?

Comment: You haven't shown us the content of `pgdroid-app-frontend`. Is `grunt` a batchfile or a .exe? If it's a batch, then you need to `CALL Grunt ....."

Comment: `grunt` is a [nodejs](http://nodejs.org) program. It basically is a  file which contains javascript code that executes in the nodejs runtime environment. I am not sure if its an exe or a batch in this sense...but let me try adding a `call` before it...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`grunt` is somewhat behaves like a `.bat` (windows batch) file or a *batch* program. Hence within a batch program, if you want to execute another batch program, you have to prefix `call` before it.

```
call grunt --force
```

Comment: it is similar with yarn