# Cannot execute additional commands after grunt build in Windows batch script

Tags: windows, gruntjs, yeoman, oracle-jet

Building an Oracle Jet app with the yeoman navdrawer template and trying to script some commons tasks I need to do (ex: build, deploy on remote server,...).

If I create a test.bat on windows with the following:

```
grunt build
echo "next command is an echo"
```

The echo command isn't executed

```
Running "build" task

Running "oraclejet-build:undefined" (oraclejet-build) task
 Oracle JET Grunt plugin
Processing Grunt command...
JET Warning: Missing platform. Default to web.
 Oracle JET Tooling
cleaning staging path.....
copy files to staging directory.....
copy finished...
copy library files to staging directory.....
copy finished...
compiling sass....
sass compile finished...
running theme injection task.....
indexHtml theme path injection finished..
running theme copy task.....
theme copy finished...
running injection task.....
mainJs paths injection finished..

Done.
```

and it return to the command line..

Why doesn't it execute the  echo command?

Answer (score 0):

Found it in another post

[grunt execution stops batch script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27729999/grunt-execution-stops-batch-script?rq=1)

must use call to make it work

```
call grunt build
echo "it works!"
```